# How to copy the sanskrit text from pdf

Tags: pdf, text, copy-paste

I have a sanskrit pdf from PVR [Ganapati Homam](http://www.vedicastrologer.org/homa/ganapathi/maha_ganapati_homam_sans_quickref.pdf)

Whenever I try to copy the Sanskrit text from it and paste it in Google , I see the English like char for e.g. /ÏSyam for the word [image] I have taken the screen shot but it is actually text. 
I am sorry if this is off topic,if so could you please guide me where should I post this question. If possible kindly see the example file for more details.
I want to copy the Sanskrit word from PDF and paste it into Google search, Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If the font has been converted in to glyphs that is curves and lines then there are no fonts included with the PDF, hence you won't be able to copy them as text